# How to query data and display them in the common layout page (_layout.cshtml)?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

I had tried the tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/intro?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

And I am able to display the data with Razor pages with page model.

However, when I was trying to find ways to display a student name at the top using the common layout page, Shared_layout.cshtml, I got lost and would hope to seek your advice on how I could query for the data from the Student Entity and display just one name in the common layout page.

I felt lost because there is no page model for the common layout page.

Note: I am new to application development, so hope you could provide some guidance to enlighten me. Any good learning reference would be great as well :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ViewBag to display student name at the top.

Add ViewBag in all your action methods where you are returning view as return type from controller files.

```
ViewBag.StudentName = "Yiwen";
```

Use it in your common layout file.

```
@ViewBag.StudentName
```

You can see microsoft link on how to use ViewBag.

Comment: @YiwenLee, Please accept this as answer and upcast vote if it helped you.

Comment: I believe ViewBag and ViewData are similar, but they did not address the issue I am facing. I would like to query specific data from the existing records in the SQL database, such as the latest saved record of the student name.


So, what other methods could I use to query for a student name based on a specific student id, then display in the common layout page.

Another challenge I was facing is to do the same to display the same specific student name in the Home page.